# Xcode How to configure Architectures in iOS SDK

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, xcode

**what are the architectures and Valid Architectures add to iOS SDK to Support**

- 32 BIT (How to configure for 32BIt)
- 64 BIT (Working Fine)
- Both 32 BIT and 64 BIT (How to configure for 32BIt).

> For 64 Bit I am using Architecture like this, its working fine

[image]

> For 32 Bit I am using Architecture like this

[image]

> In Xcode i am getting the error like this.

[image]

*How can i achieve this. Thanks in advance*

Comment: now a days by default 64 bit architecture is used in xcode

Comment: pardon....., give some scenario

Comment: @Anbu.Karthik...pls check edited one

Comment: it means it does not support to simulator, run only in device

Comment: @Anbu.Karthik....issue fixed

Answer (score 2):

> I Have fixed the Architecture issue for 32 Bit using Following Way:

[image]

for Architectures, i have used following criteria:

1) Architectures - used like **$(ARCHS_STANDARD_32_BIT)**

2) Valid Architectures - used Like **armv7** only

Answer (score 1):

nowdays, by deafult is 64 bit.

[image]

EDIT:

When you test your app in the simulator you are compiling it in your machine architecture that is probably x86_64. If what you want is to check that your app works on an arm 32 bit processor you will need to connect an iphone 5 or less and build your app for that device.